# How to integrate mocopay cross platform api?

Tags: css, api, cross-platform, payment-gateway

MOCOPAY have a nice tutorial about how to integrate MOCOPAY cross platform api in **[HERE](http://www.mocopay.com/developers/simple-integration-cross-platform-api/)**. I did not understand it, because I think it is describe by some advanced method. I did integrate some api such as TMDB api, where it's documentation is really simple and easy to understand for me. I can use just a url to get the content form tmdb,

**Example:** 
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=ABCD

So, my questions are

1. How to integrate MOCOPAY CROSS-PLATFORM API?

**And**

2. How get this screen(onetime-flow) show directly without clicking the mocopay widget button?
3. How to fit that screen within a div?

[**IMAGE**][**Onetime-flow**]

http://www.mocopay.com/app/uploads/2014/12/webflow.png